# Regexp extrair valor

Tags: python, regex

Eu tenho as seguintes strings:

> "The.Office.US.S{SE}E{EP}.The.Dundies.720p.srt"
>
> "The Office [{SE}.{EP}] The Fight.srt"

Essa string é um "template" do nome de um arquivo, os arquivos vão estar na seguinte forma

> "The.Office.US.S01E06.The.Dundies.720p.srt"
>
> "The Office [01.06] The Fight.srt"

Eu preciso extrair os valores 01 e 06 dessas strings usando python. Mas não estou conseguindo montar um regexp que funcione para o meu caso

```
#encoding: utf-8
import re
template = "The.Office.US.S{SE}E{EP}.The.Dundies.720p.srt"
arq = "The.Office.US.S01E06.The.Dundies.720p.srt"

#Nesta linha que está minha dificuldade
pat = re.compile('\{.*?\}')

season, episode = re.findall(pat, text)
print("Temporada: ", season)
print("Episódio: ", episode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem q transformar o seu template numa regex. Como ele tem varias caracteres que são especiais para uma expressão regular, você primeiro precisa escapar eles. Depois basta substituir `{SE}` e `{EP}` por um grupo pegando `[0-9]+` e pronto. O código abaixo faz isso:

```
def template2regex(template):
    template = re.escape(template)

    regex = template.replace('\{SE\}', '(?P<season>[0-9]+)')
    regex = regex.replace('\{EP\}', '(?P<episode>[0-9]+)')

    return re.compile(regex)

    template = "The.Office.US.S{SE}E{EP}.The.Dundies.720p.srt"
    regex = template2regex(template)
    regex.search('The.Office.US.S01E06.The.Dundies.720p.srt').groups()
('01', '06')
    template = 'The Office [{SE}.{EP}] The Fight.srt'
    regex = template2regex(template)
    regex.search('The Office [01.06] The Fight.srt').groups()
('01', '06')
```

Answer (score 4):

> Editada, versão final
>
> **Atende as 2 templates com uma só regex.**  
>   Essa versão resulta em uma tupla com os valores numéricos. Como a regex atende às 2 templates, a tupla sempre retornará 4 itens, sendo 2 deles `None`, a não ser que a string seja a soma das duas templates. Pode-se pegar também, os valores dos grupos separadamente, isto é, para saber o que estava entre os colchetes (template 1), considere os grupos: 'Colchete' e 'Ponto'. Para a segunda template pegue os grupos 'S' e 'E'. 
>   **Observação**  
>   O código abaixo trabalha com uma só expressão regular que, na verdade, é composta por duas [separdas pelo pipe (|)], então é possível construir uma versão mais granular, com uma regex para cada template, como exposto logo em seguida.

```
import re

s1 = "The Office [01.06] The Fight.srt"
s2 = 'The.Office.US.S01E06.The.Dundies.720p.srt'
padrao = '(?P<Colchete>\\d{2})\\.(?P<Ponto>\\d{2})|(?P<S>\\d{2})E(?P<E>\\d{2})'
re1 = re.compile(padrao)

print ('## Resultado para s1 ##')
print ('Groups: ',re1.search(s1).groups())
print ('Colchete: ', re1.search(s1).group('Colchete'))
print ('Ponto: ', re1.search(s1).group('Ponto'),'\n')

## Resultado para s1 ##
Groups:  ('01', '06', None, None)
Colchete:  01
Ponto:  06

print ('## Resultado para s2 ##')
print ('Groups: ',re1.search(s2).groups())
print ('S: ', re1.search(s2).group('S'))
print ('E: ', re1.search(s2).group('E'))

## Resultado para s2 ##
Groups:  (None, None, '01', '06')
S:  01
E:  06
```

---

Pode-se ainda fazer uma versão mais granular, quebrando a regex em 2 e trabalhar separadamente com as templates, algo assim:

```
padrao1 = '(?P<Colchete>\\d{2})\\.(?P<Ponto>\\d{2})'
padrao2 = '(?P<S>\\d{2})E(?P<E>\\d{2})'

re_p1 = re.compile(padrao1)
re_p2 = re.compile(padrao2)

print ('## Resultados para a versão Granular ##')

print ('## Para s1 ##')
print ('Groups: ',re_p1.search(s1).groups())
print ('Colchete: ', re_p1.search(s1).group('Colchete'))
print ('Ponto: ', re_p1.search(s1).group('Ponto'),'\n')

## Resultados para a versão Granular ##
## Para s1 ##
Groups:  ('01', '06')
Colchete:  01
Ponto:  06 

print ('## Para s2 ##')
print ('Groups: ',re_p2.search(s2).groups())
print ('S: ', re_p2.search(s2).group('S'))
print ('E: ', re_p2.search(s2).group('E'))

## Para s2 ##
Groups:  ('01', '06')
S:  01
E:  06
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/IglM/5)

Comment: Esta solução funcionaria apenas para a segunda string, eu preciso de algo que funcione para as duas. Sei que com um pouco de gambiarra dá para usar dessa forma. Mas preciso evitar ao máximo

Comment: É, depois q vi a outra template, editei e mudei totalmente a versao, veja que agora funciona para qq string, vc vai conseguir retirar todos os numeros, ai é só adaptar.

Comment: `\d+` pode gerar alguma encrenca caso o nome da série tenha números. Essa solução não atenderia _The 4400_

Comment: Ai vc tem que ter um padrao, pode colocar o `\d+` entre dois caracteres que a template informa, como eu disse é só adaptar. Agora.... se vier fora do padrao da template, fica paraticamente impossivel

Comment: @Sidon `r'^.*( \[([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\] |\.S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)\.).*\.srt$'`, pegando como resposta `SE=\2\4` a season o terceiro ou quarto retrovisor e `EP=\3\5` o episódio o terceiro ou quinto retrovisor; como os retrovisores 2,3 acontecem simultaneamente e 4,5 também, e que 2,3 é excludente com 4,5 , temos que essa expressão de certo modo tem mais abrangência e daria os mesmos resultados positivos ;-) Ok, essa é uma solução `sed`-ica, não pythonica, mas não é tão absurdamente longe de ser pythonizável

Comment: Encontrei uma solução bem pythonica, "roubei" do django, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @Sidon me marca quando editar?

Comment: A primeira solução se adapta mais ao meu problema, terei que fazer alguns ajustes. Mas provavelmente será algo nessa linha.

Comment: Apenas gostaria de resaltar que os templates não são fixos, o usuário que irá informar, e o que vai definir a posição dos valores são as tags {SE} e {EP}

Comment: Veja que se vier no padrao iniciado com 2 algarismos, a letrea E no meio e depois mais 2 algarismos, a regex vai sempre encontrar, não importa em que posicao estiver. A segunda solução é mais sofisticada, se vier no padrão, provavelmente nunca vai falhar. @JeffersonQuesado.

Comment: Em tempo: adaptar para a primeira template usando a segunda solução é bem simples.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, Editei novamente a resposta, com uma versão que atende as duas templates.